# Compute the Elements of the Following Quotient Polynomial Ring or Find Its Isomorphic Twin

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $\mathbb K$ be a field, and $f(x)=p(x)q(x),\,p(x),q(x)\in\mathbb K[x]$  where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are two *distinct irreducible monic* polynomials. Now, compute $\mathbb K[x]/(f(x))$, here the notation $(f(x))$ means the principle ideal generated by $f(x)$,

Here is my approach:
Notice $f(x)=p(x)q(x)$, we want to see what the relation between $(f(x))$ and $(p(x)),\, (q(x))$. It turns out that $(f(x))=(p(x))\cap(q(x))$. This is because for any element in $(f(x))$ it is "divisible" by $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ hence $(f(x))\subseteq(p(x))\cap(q(x))$. On the other hand, let $\rho(x)\in (p(x))\cap(q(x))$, then $\rho(x)=p(x)k(x)=q(x)l(x)$ for some $k(x)$ and $l(x)$ in $\mathbb K[x]$. Since $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are distinct irreducible polynomials, this indicates $k(x)=q(x)k'(x)$ and $l(x)=p(x)l'(x)$ with $k'(x)$ and $l'(x)$ are two other polynomials in $\mathbb K$. Hence $\rho(x)$ is "divisible" by $f(x)$ i.e. $(p(x))\cap(q(x))\subseteq (f(x))\Rightarrow\, (f(x))=(p(x))\cap(q(x))$.

Then I don't know what to do next. I have a thought to show that $(p(x))$ and $(q(x))$ are comaximal but which may not be true.

Comment: The question is not well-posed without saying what you mean by "isomorphic twin" and "compute $\Bbb K[x]/f$" $\ \ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque This is also my question... It is my assignment question without changing any words. It may ask you to write down all elements of the quotient ring or what it is isomorphic to...I don't know either...

Comment: Do you know some form of CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: @BillDubuque Not yet. Maybe I could search it. Is it the division algorithm of polynomials on a field?

Comment: No it's a theorem that generalizes $\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}\simeq \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for $m\land n =1 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideals $(p(x))$ and $(q(x))$ are indeed comaximal, for if not $$(p(x)),(q(x))\subset(p(x))+(q(x))\subset R$$ Which contradicts the maximality of both  $(p(x))$ and $(q(x))$

---

\begin{align}
\Bbb K[x]/(f(x)) &=\Bbb K[x]/(p(x)q(x)) \\
&=\Bbb K[x]/(p(x))(q(x)) \\
&=\Bbb K[x]/(p(x))\cap(q(x))\\
& \cong \Bbb K[x]/(p(x))\times \Bbb K[x]/(q(x)) \\
\end{align}

The first equality follows from $f(x)=p(x)q(x)$.

The second equality follows from **Result-4**

The third equality follows from **Result-1**,**Result-2** and **Result-3**

The Isomorphism follows from [The Chinese Remainder Theorem for Rings.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102037/the-chinese-remainder-theorem-for-rings)

> **Result-1:** In a PID the  ideals generated by irreducibles are maximal.
>
> **Result-2:** Let $R$  be a commutative ring with unity(CRU) and $I,J\subset R$ be two distinct maximal ideals in $R$. Then $I+J=R$
>
> **Result-3**: Let $R$ be CRU and $I,J$ be two ideals of $R$ such that $I+J=R$. Then $IJ=I\cap J$
>
> **Result-4**:Let $R$ be CRU. Then $(a)\cdot (b) = (a b)$ for any $a, b\in R$