# Chinese remainder theorem over rationals

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, rational-numbers, chinese-remainder-theorem

Is there an analogue of Chinese remainder theorem over the rationals? If I knew the residues modulo a few primes of the numerator and denominator (say $r = x/y$) of a rational number, and if I also know the range in which the rational number lies (say $[a,b]$), can I reconstruct the rational number from this information?

Comment: CRT is for all commutative rings with $1$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102037/the-chinese-remainder-theorem-for-rings).

Comment: While the CRT is true for all commutative rings, it's of no utility for fields. I think the posters is actually asking about an analogous task rather than the actual theorem.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, my application is rather algorithmic. I have a large expression involving rational numbers, which for my purpose has to be evaulated modulo a bunch of small primes and then to test some simple properties of the rational number represented by this expression. And unfortunately, I cannot simplify the whole expression to division of two integers (a rather technical reason) and implement CRT. Is there any other way out like using p-adics etc? Does the fact that I know the range help at all?

Comment: @rschwieb Can you elaborate on why you say it is useless?

Comment: @mathstudent42 the CRT is a statement about collections of comaximal ideals, but a field does not have any proper ideals which can be comaximal.

Comment: As stated, the answer to the question would be No. Let $N$ be the product of the supposedly coprime moduli. You cannot distinguish $x$ from $x+aN$ with $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, likewise you cannot distinguish $y$ from $y+bN$ where $b\in\mathbb{Z}$. With large enough $a,b$, we can bring $(x+aN)/(y+bN)$ arbitrarily close to $a/b$, which itself can be chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: Maybe relevant: [Rational reconstruction algorithm](https://www.wstein.org/books/modform/modform/linear_algebra.html#alg:ratrecon)